# How can i create a gallery for displaying photos with the swipe gesture?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I have multiple photos in an NSArray and i want to display them with the swipe gesture in full size without using [Three20](http://three20.info/) . so how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a scrollView for accomplish that :

```
UIScrollView * scroller = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGTectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:scroller];

int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++){

    UIImageView * myImageview = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
    [myImageview setImage:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [scroller addSubview:myView];

    x += myView.frame.size.width;

}

[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, 480)];
```

Answer (score 1):

This Code works for me great:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
 scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
 NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
  CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
  UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
  awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
  [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];
   [awesomeView release];
  }
  scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
  [self.view addSubview:scroll];
  [scroll release];
```